# Proving $2^n(-1)^n$ is bounded or unbounded

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do you prove $2^n(-1)^n$ is bounded or unbounded?

Does it suffice to take $|2^n(-1)^n| \le 2^n$ and state as $n \to \infty$ the sequence also approaches $\infty$ so I can conclude it is unbounded.

Is this an accepted way to conclude the proof?

Comment: It is always true (in my world, at least) that the sequence is bounded or unbounded.

Comment: $|2^n(-1)^n|=2^n\to\infty$.

Comment: Well, not exactly. You should have $|2^n (-1)^n| = 2^n$, ie, $=$, not $\le$ (you want $|2^n (-1)^n| \ge 2^n$ to conclude unboundedness). If you know that $\lim_n 2^n = \infty$, then yes, this is an acceptable proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we denote $u_n=2^n(-1)^n$ then the subsequence $u_{2n}=2^{2n}=4^n\to+\infty$ so the sequence $(u_n)$ is  unbounded.